# My apex page doesnt show any fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created an apex page which is supposed to show record details for my customer portal authenticated usr on my force.com site.

They can see the field data on the datatable in my archive page that I also created, however on the linked apex detail page no fields are shown. The ID is passed as a parameter and according to the [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller), this is possible.

Initially I thought it may be permissions issue, but if they can see the data in the archive page I do not see why that would be a problem.

**Apex:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" title="Order Detail" standardController="Service_Order__c" recordSetVar="orders">
  <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
    <apex:define name="body">  

    <h2>Order Detail</h2>
    <h3><apex:outputText value="{!Service_Order__c.Name}"/></h3>

    <p><apex:outputText value="{!Service_Order__c.description__c}"/></p>

    </apex:define>
  </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you try removing recordsetVar?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava That fixed it! Could you convert this into an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When recordSetVar is used it displays all the list of Sobjects and hence that should not be used unless the intention is to display list of records and use pagination using standard list controller .

So the correct code for this will be

```
 <apex:page showHeader="false" title="Order Detail" standardController="Service_Order__c"  >
  <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
 <apex:define name="body">  

<h2>Order Detail</h2>
<h3><apex:outputText value="{!Service_Order__c.Name}"/></h3>

<p><apex:outputText value="{!Service_Order__c.description__c}"/></p>

</apex:define>
 </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```